# Select multiple options and selection values will come from Excel

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What I am trying to do is select multiple options from this example site while holding CTRL

http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_SELECT_MULTIPLE.html

The multiple selection values would come from excel though, means if the excel rows has values as mushroom, onions and olives each on different rows (within same column) it will select only those values one by one within the page. The Excel file looks like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMb3h.png

And this is the code I got so far upto

```
package mineP;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Various {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

                File src = new File("C:\\Users\\Documents\\myP2.xlsx");

                // Load file
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);

                // Load WB
                XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

                // Load Sheet

                XSSFSheet sh1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);



        String chromePath = "C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromePath);



        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_SELECT_MULTIPLE.html");


        WebElement sel = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='toppings']"));

        List<WebElement> alloptions = sel.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@name='toppings']//option"));

        for (WebElement option: alloptions) {

            String optTxt = option.getText();

            //System.out.println(optTxt);

            if (optTxt.contains(sh1.getRow(3).getCell(1).getStringCellValue())){

                option.click();
            }

        }



    }
}
```

What i am trying to do is as long as there is a value in excel it will loop through excel and the options within the website and keep on selecting all the options using CTRL whose text values are located in excel

Comment: Welcome to SO. I can't quite put my finger on your question. Where in your code are you finding an error or issue?

Comment: Sorry abt that updated the question. What i am trying to do is as long as there is a value in excel it will loop through excel and the options within the website and keep on selecting all the options using CTRL whose text values are located in excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like a real user would do, you can hold the Ctrl key and click on each element:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_SELECT_MULTIPLE.html");
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@name='toppings']//option"));

// Values to select
List<String> values =  Arrays.asList("onions", "olives");

// Select all the options
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL);
for (WebElement option: options){
    if(values.contains(option.getText())) {
        act.click(option);
    }
}
act.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);
act.perform();

driver.quit();
```

And to load data from a workbook to a ListArray:

```
List<String> values =  new ArrayList<String>();

FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("C:\\file.xlsx");
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> rows = worksheet.rowIterator();
while (rows.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rows.next();
    if(row.getRowNum() > 0) {                             // skip first row
        values.add(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());  // add the second cell
    }
}
stream.close();
```

Comment: but values are not coming from excel. The code you have used in that are static values provided by me. I want the values coming from excel and by looping I want to keep on selecting all the options as long as there is a value in excel. and values might change over time within excel so selection will change too. Thanks.

Comment: I added an example to load the data from a workbook to a ListArray.

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you be kind enough to stitch both codes to show how it would work together please? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much @florentbr It worked :D. Combined them and worked without any issue. Here is the combined code if anyone needs it -

```
// =========The SpreadSheet=========

    File src = new File("C:\\file.xlsx");

    // Load file
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);

    // Load WB
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

    // Load Sheet
    XSSFSheet sh1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    // ==========The Browser===========

    String chromePath = "C:\\chromedriver.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromePath);

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_SELECT_MULTIPLE.html");

    List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@name='toppings']//option")); //Find the options within this element within the page

    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();  //values from excel will be stored within this array

    Iterator<Row> rows = sh1.rowIterator();


    while (rows.hasNext()) 
    {

        Row row = rows.next();

        if (row.getRowNum() > 0) 
        {

            values.add(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());

        }
    }

    System.out.println(values);

    Actions act= new Actions(driver);

    act.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL);

    for (WebElement option:options) 
    {

        if (values.contains(option.getText())) {
            act.click(option);
        }
    }

    act.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);
    act.perform();

    Thread.sleep(2000);



    fis.close();
```

Amazing Guys. Thanks so much.